# HecGeoRas using Python

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap, hec-ras

I want to automatize the process where I can change the profile values of flow data and load it in arcmap using hecgeoras for flood mapping. I want to use python to access hecgeoras tool of arcmap and use this tool to load different flow data exported from hec-ras.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show some code.

Comment: using hecras and arcmap, I have generated a flood map but haven't yet written a program.

Comment: Then you should at first try it on your own.